# NIntegrate: The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {}{}

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I encountered a problem with the NIntegrate function while simulating a physical situation. The expression is quite messy, but it is just an integration over a polynomial so it should be possible. I want to integrate the function over kP and Energy, and then plot the results with T varying from 0 to 10.

```
    simplifiednumThermalConductivityIntegrationContentPosSpin=
{-((4.24285*10^44 (1.00032*10^-30 - 
    6.371*10^-31 Energy)^2 (1.3836*10^6 + 1. Energy^6 + 
    259200. kP^4 + 
    Energy^5 (0.000999182 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       1.41159 kP^2) - 
    598856. Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
     2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] + 
    kP^2 (-1.19771*10^6 + 
       259200. Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2]) + 
    Energy^2 (-2.306*10^11 - 
       1.26035*10^-8 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       4.32*10^10 kP^4 + 
       3.32698*10^10 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] - 
       3.72529*10^-9 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] + 
       kP^2 (1.99619*10^11 - 
          1.44*10^10 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
           2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2])) + 
    Energy^4 (9.35396*10^10 - 1.5 kP^4 - 
       1.68212 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] - 
       0.00146484 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] + 
       kP^2 (2. - 0.000403313 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
          1.88631 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
           2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2])) + 
    Energy (2.91038*10^-11 - 
       7.68665*10^7 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       1.44*10^7 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] kP^4 + 
       1.16415*10^-10 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] - 
       3.32698*10^7 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] + 
       1.44*10^7 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2]
         kP^2 (4.6208 + 
          1. Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
           2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2])) + 
    Energy^3 (-9.37702*10^-6 + 
       3.11799*10^7 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       0.000476971 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] kP^4 - 
       7.62939*10^-6 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] + 
       kP^2 (0.0000145193 + 
          0.000976563 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] + 

          0.00146484 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] Sqrt[
           2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
           2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2]))) Sech[(
   5800.46 (-1.57011 + Energy))/
   T])/((1. Energy - 
    0.001 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2]) (1. Energy + 
    0.001 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2]) (Sqrt[-9 + 
      1000000 Energy^2] (-0.0023104 + 0.001 kP^2 + 
       0.003 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2]) + 
    Energy (2.3104 - 8.88178*10^-20 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       1. kP^2 + 
       1. Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2])) (Sqrt[-9 + 
      1000000 Energy^2] (-0.0023104 + 0.001 kP^2 + 
       0.003 Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2]) + 
    Energy (2.3104 + 1.77636*10^-19 Sqrt[-9 + 1000000 Energy^2] - 
       1. kP^2 + 
       1. Sqrt[2.3104 - 1.47148 Energy - kP^2] Sqrt[
        2.3104 + 1.47148 Energy - kP^2])) T^2))}
```

Now, trying the following line, I get the `NIntegrate::inumr` error in the headline:

```
answer = NIntegrate[simplifiednumThermalConductivityIntegrationContentPosSpin,
{kP, 0, 1}, {Energy, 0, Infinity}]
```

I have also tried to integrate the energy only from 0 to 0.55, but that won't solve the problem.

Do any of you have any tips as to what I should try to be able to plot this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the integrand at a point in the integration region?

Comment: Yes, that sort of work. But apparently there are some troubles with the expression since it gives 0 + 0i for almost any combination of the three variables.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the result have symbols `T` in it, or did you plug in a number for `T` as well?  Note that `NIntegrate` substitutes values only for `kP` and `Energy`. To test whether your integrand evaluates to a numeric value, you should substitute numbers only for the integration variables `kP` and `Energy`.

Comment: More to the actual point, yes, your integrand is poorly scaled for machine precision, which has a lower limit for representing a positive real number of around `10^-308`.  You might `Rationalize[]` the integrand and use a higher `WorkingPrecision`, or it might be better if you could pick more convenient units for your integral (convenient for the use of machine-precision floating point numbers).

Comment: When I feed it with only kP and Energy, it gives out an Indeterminate expression error.

Comment: It depends on what numbers you use. I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tCNKn.png -- which underflows if I set `T` equal to a positive number under `8000`.  Note also that it is a list `{}` and not a plain number.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetDelay`,

```
answer[T_] := NIntegrate[simplifiednumThermalConductivityIntegrationContentPosSpin, {kP, 0,
1}, {Energy, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

The output is expected to be a complex, so here I plotted both real and imaginary,

```
Plot[{Re@answer[T], Im@answer[T]}, {T, 0, 10}]
```

[image]